# Macbook Air Running version 10.7.5 won't connect to wifi but connects via Ethernet

Tags: wifi, macbook-pro, airport, ethernet

I have a MBA and I have connected to my home network before. I went on holiday and on return, I cannot connect to Wifi anymore.

It tells me "connection time-out occurred". But my Ipod Touch (4th Gen) and Samsung Galaxy S2 can connect to the home wifi network and everyone else (I live with friends) has no issues with the wi-fi.

I already tried removing all the "Preferred networks" and tried to do an SMC reset on my Macbook Air. Nothing worked. I also went into Keychain and removed home network from there. Still not resolved

I then tried tethering my MBA to my Samsung Galaxy S2's wifi and I could connect and surf normally. (so I concluded nothing is wrong with my laptop's Airport/wifi utility)

Finally I decided to try and connect my MBA to the router via Ethernet cable, and I am able to surf and go online as normal

I updated all my software on the laptop and it is still not working. I can find my home network and click on it but when I input the password, it says "Connection Failed". I also tried setting up the network manually and inputting the password but again "Connection Failed"

I am unable to get into the router as I don't have the IP address for it. Does anyone else have a similar problem?

I have yet to try to connect to a neighbour's Wi-Fi but I will try that tonight.

Comment: Maybe your router went on a vacation? Just kidding...Somehow your router was reset. Try resetting it to factory settings (make sure you know the log in information before you do that).

Comment: Hahaha good one. I wish it did... But I don't know the log in information. It's a D-link and I tried the usual 192.168.0.1 and 192.168.1.1 but I can't get in. 

I'm just curious why my other devices aren't affected. But at least I know my laptop wifi isn't screwed up *thank god!*

Comment: there should be a label on the back of it, on the label is the log in info. usually it is as simple as user + administrator. i do not know about other devices lets focus on the problematic one.

Comment: and leave the neighbor out of this, he might not be to happy hacking his router. You can actually reset the router using one of the working devices and connecting to the routers set up page, still needs a password.

Comment: → Steph: could you please add to your original question the IP address you got when you are trying to connect to your wireless network?
Did you check that you are really connecting to  your own wireless network and not the one of a neighbour?

Comment: → Steph: from your description, your wireless interface is working, your OS is working, your SMC is working (no need to reset it on this kind of problem). Your network configuration is working on Ethernet. Your network configuration on Wireless is not correct. Many errors may have occured there.
If you want a targeted fix, feel free to include a screen capture of your Wireless configuration within your original question.

Answer (score 1):

1. Try resetting any proxy settings you may have enabled (go to System Preferences > Network > Advanced > Proxy)
2. Reset your router
3. Attempt to connect via WPS if your router supports it
4. Find the IP address of your router and enter it into the URL bar of your browser

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in the following post, check it out:

https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/150723/405776

I write here the method too:

1. Restart your Mac.
2. Upon start-up, hold down the Opt key until you see your drives.
3. Click on the recovery drive (note: this will not affect or delete any files you currently have).
4. Login if needed.
5. In the top right-hand corner you will see the Wi-Fi icon (hopefully). Click the icon and then click "turn wifi Off" and then again click "turn wifi ON"
6. Restart your Mac again and start it up normally.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same error on my MAC-Book PRO and it turned out to be a MAC address issue. these are the steps I took:

- Reset router to default settings
- Remove network from saved network.
- Search for network.

If this doesn't work, you might have to add the network manually.

Hope this helps.

Comment: if you want some points be more precise in your answer, how to reset the router, where is the factory log in saved, ho to remove the network saved, how to manually add network, I know it is SF but sometimes necessary :)

Comment: can you let me know what router you are using? normally most routers have a hard reset button towards the back and that should do the trick.
For removing network from saved networks:
Network Preferences -> WIFI -> Advanced.
You will see a list of your saved networks where you can remove. Also, the '+' button will allow you to add a network manually.