# How to install wifi in Macbook Pro

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, wifi, spotlight

Currently I am using a MacBook Pro with OS X 10.8.5 and I just noticed that there is no Wi-Fi option on this machine.

To try to add Wi-Fi to the menu bar, I went to System Preferences → Network and clicked the "+" button from the left list, and in the interfaces section I found nothing named Wi-Fi!

I also tried to search for "wifi" in Spotlight, but there is nothing named like that.

I'm wondering if somehow the software is not installed in this machine. I don't know whether this software comes with the OS X installation or not.

[image: System Preferences Network Interfaces]

[image: System Information: Wi-Fi]

Comment: It's almost as if your Macbook doesn't see its Wifi hardware. Try opening "System Information" from the Utilities folder and looking for Wi-Fi under Networks there. Does it say anything?

Comment: @AlistairMcMillan Thanks for commenting. Yes there is something. The details are about Software versions. 

`  Software Versions:
  CoreWLAN: 3.4 (340.18)
  CoreWLANKit: 2.0.2 (202.11)
  Menu Extra: 8.1 (810.11)
  configd plug-in: 8.5 (850.252)
  System Information: 8.3 (830.5)
  IO80211 Family: 5.3 (530.5)
  Diagnostics: 2.1 (210.25)
  AirPort Utility: 6.3.1 (631.4)`

Comment: Below the "Software" text, there should be text just below that for "Interfaces". Does it have this text about Interfaces?

Comment: @AlistairMcMillan I attach the screen shot in my post. This is what I found.

Comment: So your Macbook isn't seeing its Wi-Fi hardware at all. Did you have Wi-Fi on this Macbook before? For the sake of testing, if you restart your Mac, hold down the Option key and choose Recovery does it offer your wireless networks then?

Comment: Yes, I am pretty sure that, this machine had wifi before. And right now, the actual user of this Mac tell me, after migrating the OSX, the wifi option disappear. If I do Recovery, is there any chance of erasing HD file or something?? I don't have any idea about it. Just asking for safety.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15854/discussion-between-alistair-mcmillan-and-tulon).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same issue and finally found a fix!!

Not only did I NOT have wifi, but I didn't even have an option for "wifi" under network preferences.  When clicking the (+) under network preferences I only got options for Firewire, Ethernet, Bluetooth DUN, VPN PPPoE, and 6 to 4.

I tried a number of "fixes" including terminal commands to manually turn the airport power off and on again, deleting the existing wifi option (the one that wouldn't turn On) using the (-) button, and restarting my mac numerous times both in Mac OS and my bootcamp Windows OS.

Finally, i fixed this issue doing the following:

1. Restart your Mac.
2. upon start-up, hold down the <kbd>Opt</kbd> key until you see your drives.
3. click on the **recovery drive** (note: this will not affect or delete any files you currently have).
4. login if needed.
5. in the top right hand corner you will see the **Wi-Fi icon** (hopefully). Click the icon and then click "**turn wifi Off**" and then again click "**turn wifi ON**"
6. restart your Mac again and start it up normally.
7. recover from your near-heart attack

Please let me know if this worked.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I've followed your 1 to 4 steps & then after clicking on the wifi icon, I found `Wi-Fi: No hardware installed` just beneath the icon. That means no Wifi hardware is installed in this machine. Do you have any suggestion about installing it? I mean how can I get that hardware? Is it available on internet?
Thanks a lot again. :)

Answer (score 2):

You could have a hardware problem with your network card.

When there is no wifi hardware installen/found on the mac, I would go to an apple store or authorised service provider to have this problem fixed. When your mac is still in warrenty, it normally is free to repair.

When it is out of warranty I would first call Apple care to see if they will repair as a gesture of goodwill.

You will get a case ID than. With that ID you can go to a service provider to repair your mac for free.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I understand the solution of it. My warrenty expired a long time ago, so I've to take it to a Doctor. :(